# Trying to return the number of differences between two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

So if I have two arrays

```
int [] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}
int [] array2 = {1, 3, 2, 4}
```

This would return two as there are two differences in the arrays so far I have this but I can't figure it out.

```
    public static int countDifferences(int[] array1, int[] array2){
    int differences = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<array2.length; j++) {
            if(array1[i]==array2[j]) {
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                differences++;
            }
        }
    }
    return differences;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to check if the n index of array1 and array2 are of same value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just have a single `for` loop to iterate once over both arrays.  You also need to handle the case where the two input arrays do not have the same length.  Also, one or both arrays could be empty.  For these edge cases I am returning -1, though you can modify if you want.

```
public static int countDifferences(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    if (array1 == null || array2 == null || array1.length != array2.length) {
        return -1;
    }
    int differences = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {
            differences++;
        }
    }

    return differences;
}
```

Comment: The arrays have two differences however, it returned 4.

Comment: I doubt this.  Are you sure you are using my actual code?

Comment: Sorry I was running a reverse array method before it but now its working thank you.

Comment: You should check `array1 != null || array2 != null` first.

Answer (score 0):

This is a logic problem.

For your example, you are counting the same difference twice, since the switch of two location is really one switch.  So check for that condition and count it as one.